# Clearing text from otherwise empty combobox (active x)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, activex

I have a bunch of Comboboxes (ActiveX elements) and want to loop through all of them to fill them if there's an x next to it and empty them if there is not. This already works, but I'm getting an error when I try clearing the text/value of the the combobox after it has been emptied. Any ideas why?

```
Dim ws2 as worksheet
Dim ComBx As OLEObject
Dim Name As String
Dim NameParaWS3
Dim ComboFill As Range
Dim VisibleFill As Range

For Each ComBx In ws2.OLEObjects
ComBx.ListFillRange = ""
    If ComBx.progID Like "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
        If ws2.Cells(ComBx.TopLeftCell.row, AlphaCol).Value = "X" Then
        Name = ws2.Cells(ComBx.TopLeftCell.row, 2).Value
        Set NameParaWS3 = ws3.Range("1:1").Find(Name, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set ComboFill = ws3.Range(ws3.Cells(2, NameParaWS3.Column), ws3.Cells(LastRow3, NameParaWS3.Column))
        Set VisibleFill = ComboFill.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Debug.Print ComBx.Name & " located at " & ComBx.TopLeftCell.Address(False, False, xlA1) & ", belongs to parameter '" & Name & "' and is alphanumeric"
            With ComBx
                .ListFillRange = ComboFill.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True)
            End With
        Else:   ComBx.ListFillRange = ""

 'This is the part where I'm getting the error.None of these worked:
                'ComBx.Clear
                'ComBx.Value = ""
                'ComBx.Text= ""
        End If
    End If
Next ComBx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.Object` property of the `OLEObject` to retrieve the `ComboBox` object and its usual methods.

```
ComBx.Object.value = ""
```

You can even dim a variable a `Combobox` and have Intellisense for its methods:

```
Dim cmb as ComboBox: Set cmb = ComBx.Object
cmb.value = ""
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I didn't understand how to use the OLEObject yet so I'll look into it

Comment: @DaSpotz you're welcome. An `OleObject` is a general container for "Object Linking and Embedding". The `.Object` property returns the actual embedded object, which is here a `ComboBox` Activex control (but it could be anything else in the general case).